# Consuming a ColdFusion WSDL Web Service in Csharp .net

Tags: .net, service, coldfusion, wsdl

When I create a web reference & create an instance of the service in code I end up with an object of `service.Map` after I call the method in the web service I am invoking. What do I do with this? How do I get a String back from the request that I can turn into an xml document or something? The web reference URI has ?WSDL at the end.

Example:

```
WebReferenceName.ServiceIAmInvoking service = 
    new WebReferenceName.ServiceIAmInvking();

var getValue = service.MethodInService(param, param);
```

This just seems to get me an object of `service.Map`.

I don't understand what to do with `service.Map`.

The map object has two properties Item & ItemValue both of which are null.

[image]

I wonder if this is because Visual Studio is having problems with the "Encoded" maybe it should be "literal".

Resolution: This was indeed the issue I talked with the Coldfusion services guy and now I get a string back which I can turn into an xml doc in code.

Comment: You will need to post more information and code samples for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: This was indeed the issue I talked with the Coldfusion services guy and now I get a string back which I can turn into an xml doc in code.

Comment: *What* was the issue exactly? :) It would help others if you expanded your answer to include the problematic code, what it was changed to instead, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` object most likely is a DataContract generated for the WSDL. It represents the message returned by the webservice as a .NET object with properties you can access.

Put a breakpoint after the service call and Inspect or Watch the `getValue` variable to see which properties it contains.

Comment: Two properties it has Item & ItemValue both of which are null. I wonder if this is because Visual Studio is having problems with the use of "encoded" above.